# C# Find Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am trying to access the controls on a helper class file and I can't seem to find the control.

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FoxHelper p = new FoxHelper();

    //  load page
    p.loadFoxPage(this.Page);
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public void loadFoxPage(Page thePage)
{
    //  set the master page
    m = (SiteN)thePage.Master;

    HtmlGenericControl ctrl = (HtmlGenericControl)thePage.FindControl("ADMMgM");
}
```

Why can't I reference the control from the other class file.  Note:  it is not a partial class of the page.  I use this helper class for 25 different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `FindControl` doesn't find nested controls. From MSDN:

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="I'm here!" />
</asp:Panel>
```

In the previous exampleif you look for the Label, `FindControl` won't find it. Instead, if you look for the Panel it will find it.

More info here:

[Control.FindControl Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I pass in the page and the control is on that page.  Shouldn't that work?

Comment: @user3405511 not if the control you want is nested in another control in the page.

Comment: What I mean is that if your control is inside another control, let's say a `Panel`, that method will not find it.

Answer (score 3):

FindControl does not look for nested control. This is a recursive find control, credits to [coding horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/).

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)  
{
    if (root.ID == id)  
    {
        return root;  
    }

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)  
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);  
        if (t != null)  
        {
            return t;  
        }
    }
    return null;  
}
```